# The app won't run unless you update google play servicesse

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase, google-play-services-3.3.0

I had a expo project, and due to some limitations i have detached
I added firebase to the project using react-native-firebase package and it needs some native code modifications
After many head shake, finally i ran it on the emulator successfully, But it ask to update google play unless the app won't run

In our region user doesn't update it regularly so it leads to bad UX.

I know its due to using google play service newest version , But is there's a way to use google play service low version with same functionality firebase provide for the top version? if not what kind of feature i will lose ?